# sessionStorage listener is only detecting manual chnages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since I have to make communication accros two different components (rendered separately => must be like that) in hybrid web app, I have to catch chnages into sessionStorage. I am at the moment using listener to do such a thing and it works perfectly if you manualy go to "Application" and change storage item there, not through javascript.

```
window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
   setAmount(someAmount);
   console.log(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("items")));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a function, and then call/invoke that function wherever you're updating session storage?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically you have to include on click event or something, a dispatch method like this:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
```